# Tracking the vertices

Tags: vertices

I have a 3D hand model. Using the model, I created some hand pose animations and extracted hundreds of sequences of obj files. From these obj files, I labeled some key joints located on the fingers and I did it manually by selecting their corresponding vertices. I repeated the same labeling procedure for a few other frames. Since I have many obj frames, I want to automate the labeling process, so I wrote a python script to track the vertex indices I am interested in. However, it does not work as the vertex indices change from one frame to another (change with time).
Do you know what is the best way to keep tracking the vertices?

Comment: one way would be to parent the vertices to another object e.g. empties and then you can deal with the empties positions instead of indices of vertices

Comment: @Chris, Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help